# Loose equality in Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

In my test, I am passing an object that has two boolean values (among other values) to my API. I am then testing that the object was stored correctly in my database. The response should be exactly the same as the input, except that MySql stores booleans as integers.

I would like to test all of the fields without repetitive code, so I have written this:

```
const validChannel = {
    id: `${new Date().getTime()}`,
    major_nbr: 2,
    minor_nbr: 1,
    delivery: 'ATSC1',
    display_nbr: '2.10',
    opt_in: true,
    visible: true,
    callsign: 'TEST',
};

const channel = api.get();
Object.keys(validChannel).forEach((k) => {
   expect(channel[k]).to.equal(validChannel[k]);
});
```

This works great, except that Mocha uses strict comparison, so 1 != true. How can I make this work while still keeping it compact?

Comment: `expect(val1==val2).to.equal(true)`

Comment: Maybe `expect(channel[k]).to.deep.equal(validChannel[k])`?

Comment: @AndrewNolan, I tried deep.equal before unfortunately. Its intended for checking equality between arrays. It performs a deep copy, but it still checks each item strictly.

Comment: The answer you have accepted is deeply flawed. FYI